# Moving a system partition to new Hardware with Win8/UEFI, without screwing up BCD

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, bcd

My existing Win 8 install is historically installed on a MBR dynamic disk (that's so I can soft mirror the data partition which is on the same disk). I just bought a new motherboard/new HDD, and I want to migrate my OS to the new EFI style boot on it.

This is what I tried:

1. I connected both old and new HDDs to the new motherboard and booted the old one, to check it works. It boots fine and recognises the new HDD as "uninitialised", so no driver issues etc.
2. I then set the new HDD as the boot device, and "clean installed" Win 8 onto the new HDD, to get the right EFI partitions set up and so on.
3. Win 8 was now working in EFI mode on the new HDD and motherboard. The new disk was GPT/EFI structured, and everything was working fine. So the boot setup is correct.
4. With the new HDD containing all the correct support partitions for EFI on the new motherboard, all that remains in theory is to transfer my existing win 8 system volume to the new disk, by overwriting the volume that holds Win 8 from the new install (ie new HDD's C drive). At worst I might have to change its GUID or and unplug the old HDD. BCD on the new HDD will then have a system volume in the same place it expects to find one, and will think that this volume is still the same one it expected to find for booting purposes. Image for Windows and Partition Minitool Server 8 both handle copying a system volume onto a GPT disk. No sweat expected, or at most a minor edit to BCD.

Unfortunately when I try doing this, I keep getting BCD errors I can't resolve and "system repair" can't fix. Standard CMD tools like bootrec/rebuildbcd don't seem to solve it either. As far as I know I hadn't modified the BCD store in any other way either. It's probably something simple, but I'm stuck.

What am I missing, and how do I get it working?

Comment: What software did you use to create the image the default Windows tool can't do what is required to covert a MBR disk image to a GPT partition

Comment: Tried it 3 ways: 1) backed up and restored using Image for Windows, 2) direct disk-to-disk copy using Image for Windows, 3) Minitool partition Wizard Server Edition 8. All 3 handle the scenario and appear to have correctly restored the volume to the correct place on the new HDD, but in each case there's clearly some manual update required to the BCD/EFI or something, as well, which I can't figure out. I haven't any reason to believe the copied data is incorrect or drivers missing, though - the errors consistently suggest boot/BCD/EFI config issues rather than integrity of the copying process.

Comment: Also to clarify from your comment, I didn't copy over the entire disk. I copied the existing Win 8 system partition/volume (only) from the old disk, by overwriting the data in the Win 8 system partition/volume (only) on the new HDD, leaving recovery partitions, HDD MBR, track 1, disk sig/GUID, and (as far as I am aware) everything else unchanged.